# How to merge two learning rate schedulers in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to use OneCycleLR for warming up the LR from a low value, then decreasing the LR from peak with ReduceLROnPlateau.

I understand that I could simulate ReduceLROnPlateau manually after increasing LR with OneCycleLR, but is there a simpler way to use these two schedulers together directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check approach at here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/24352 , After #22107

Comment: sadly they are not landed for some reason..

Comment: I was looking at https://pytorch.org/ignite/contrib/handlers.html#example-with-ignite-contrib-handlers-concatscheduler , and it looks promising

Answer (score 1):

PyToch has released a [method](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/26423), on github instead of official guidelines.

You can try the following snippet:

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Parameter
from torch.optim import SGD
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ExponentialLR, StepLR

model = [Parameter(torch.randn(2, 2, requires_grad=True))]
optimizer = SGD(model, 0.1)

scheduler1 = ExponentialLR(optimizer, gamma=0.9)
scheduler2 = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)

for epoch in range(10):

    print(epoch, scheduler2.get_last_lr()[0])

    optimizer.step()
    scheduler1.step()
    scheduler2.step()
```

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a special [ChainedScheduler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ChainedScheduler.htmlhttps://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ChainedScheduler.html) in PyTorch, which simply calls schedulers one by one. But to be able to use it all the schedulers have to be "chainable", as it is written in docs.